# VBA Macro on Word: Insert tag when text found

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document of 170 pages. I want to identify the pages that includes a particular name. Then, when found, I want to write a little note at the end of the page:

#### Example:

> *Name searched* : "Article : Kr"
>   *Note to write at the end of the page concerned* : "DefaultKr"

Every time try to resolve this I obtain a different result.

```
Sub Find()
    Dim Page As Integer
    Dim Fin As Integer
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToFirst
    Windows("g-1.doc").Activate
    Page = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    While (CurrentPage <= Page)
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "Article : KR"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        End With
        If Selection.Find.Text = "Article : KR" Then GoTo Jim1
        Jim1:
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.TypeText ("DéfautsKR")
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "Article : IP"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        End With
        If Selection.Find.Text = "Article : IP" Then GoTo Jim2
        Jim2:
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.TypeText ("DéfautsIP")
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext
        CurrentPage = CurrentPage + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ryan: A good edit, but please also always check the tags. I improved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I haven't understand you completely wrong, this should help. It Searches through the document and if the search string is found it writes a footnote:

```
Sub OnOpen()
Dim Page As Integer
Dim Fin As Integer

Windows("Dok1.docm").Activate

Call SearchAndMark("Article : KR", "DéfautsKR")
Call SearchAndMark("Article : IP", "DéfautsIP")

End Sub
'---------------------------------------------
Sub SearchAndMark(searchString As String, markText As String)
    Dim CurrentPage As Integer
    Dim LastPage As Integer

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToFirst
    CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    LastPage = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)

    While (CurrentPage < LastPage)
        Selection.Find.Forward = True
        Selection.Find.Text = searchString
        Selection.Find.Execute

        If Selection.Find.Found Then
            CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            Debug.Print "Found on Page " & CurrentPage
            Call ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Add(Selection.Range, "", markText)
        Else
            'To exit the loop if the search string isn't found (anymore)
            CurrentPage = LastPage
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

I wasn't completely sure what you meant by "... write a little note at the end of the page"

Comment: Yes, i want the footnote to be written at the end of the page, because my pages are independent! Each page should be treated solitarily.
Your answer may be very helpful to me, i'll verify the execution.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Problems found:**
1) Are you trying to add the information at the end of the document or at the end of each page? selection.endkey unit:=wdStory writes your comments at the end of the document. Is that where you want it?

2) If you add one or more comments to the end of each page, your pagination will change.

**Solution overview**
It seems like you want to find an array of names and document where you find them. Two options which would allow you to document where the names are found without messing the print would be 1) find the names and insert comments and 2) find the names and change the highlight/background color. Comments will not print unless explicitly instructed. All background colors can be reset to white just prior to printing.

**Answer**
As far as the programming, I would probably create an array of the selected names, loop through the array of names and set variables with select case, find the variables and either highlight or add a comment to mark the variable. You can always move to the end of the current page to add text as you have proposed.

```
Dim NameArray("name1", "name2", ect) As String
Selection.HomeKey wdStory
With NameArray
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = NameArray
        While .Found
            Select Case NameArray
                Case "name1"
                    myIndex = wdRed
                    myText = "DefaultName1"
                Case "name2"
                    myIndex = wdYellow
                    myText = "DefaultName2"
                Case Else
                    GoTo skipme
            End Select
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = myIndex
            or
            Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            ActiveDocument.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, _
                Text:=myText
        Wend
    End With
End With
```

Comment: I am trying to add just one comment at the end of each page depending on the name found there ! Names searched cant exist in the same page.
Your answer may be very helpful to me, i'll verify the execution. Thank you !